# How to add an entry to Datagrid in GWT

Tags: gwt, datagrid

I know the way that initialize datagrid with data.
But I want to be able to add entry at runtime with add button and a form.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a List of the objects which your DataGrid should contain. Also you can append an object to the list, if you want to add a new entry.The objects should be of the same type as your DataGrid,you are defining it when you create or extend the Datagrid (between the < > ) . Then call the `.setRowData(list)` and the datagrid will be filled up. If you want to add a new list, clear the datagrid before and call `.setRowCount(0)`.